# Not able too perform any activity after successfull login page automation in UI path Studio

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

[image: Login page] after successfull login automation when its redirects too dashboard page i am not able too perform any activity on dashboard page  using UIPath Studio  [image: Dashboard]

i was trying too perform click activity on dashboard page elemnts

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your window selector is updated once you move on to the next page.  I have seen in almost every single automation I have created, the Login page has a different window title than the actual web app screens after login.

With the Modern Design Experience in UiPath, the Window selector is a little hidden from the rest of the selector, so make sure you open the Window Selector dropdown in the Selector Window (or modify the Window Selector property in the properties pane) to modify that when advancing from the Login screen to the main app screen.